# Return access denied with access control

Tags: symfony, security, symfony4, access-control

I'm using Symfony 4.1.7 in my `security.yaml` have this access control:

```
access_control:
    # master:
    - { path: ^/master, roles: ROLE_MASTER }
    # manager:
    - { path: ^/.*/manager, roles: ROLE_MANAGER }
    # main:
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

when i open the second one url `(/foo/manager)` and not authorized i will redirected to login path i need to return access denaid not redirect to login.
my last goal is call event listener for append role to authorize user from event listener.

**Update:**
Here is my security firewall section:

```
 main:
        pattern: ^/
        user_checker: App\Security\Checker\UserChecker
        anonymous: ~
        provider: default
        context: primary
        simple_form:
            authenticator: App\Security\Authenticator\UserAuthenticator
            check_path: login
            login_path: login
            username_parameter: phone
            password_parameter: password
            use_referer: true
        logout:
            path: logout
        remember_me:
            secret: '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 604800
            path: /
            remember_me_parameter: remember_me
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo need to configure the `login_path` en the security.yml

Example:

```
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
    in_memory: { memory: ~ }
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern:             .*
        context:            user
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /login_check
            failure_path:   null
```

[Symfony Doc.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#login-path)

Comment: I had login path. I'm update and add the firewall codes i need the access denied not redirect to login

Comment: Try to add the `use_forward` parameter like my example.

Comment: It solved my problem. Really changed my life. Thank you Eze.

Comment: @EzequielEsnaola not worked I added the `logout_on_user_change` and implemented the `EquatableInterface` but the `logout_on_user_change` firewall option is deprecated and will be removed in 5.0.

Comment: @EzequielEsnaola problem solved I was deleted the `logout_on_user_change` and it's worked only with `EquatableInterface`, tnx for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow users to access this path and instead use your controller to check the user role.

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_MANAGER ', null, 'Unable to access this page!');
```

or

```
$this->isGranted('ROLE_MANAGER');
```

Depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry @A.Seddighi misunderstood your question, edited.

Comment: If I do it I need to write it to all controllers I think it is not a good way to do it

Comment: It's the right way to do it @A.Seddighi... `access_control` in `security.yml` is here to help you set global rules and simply block access to some paths based on roles. If you really want what you need, you need to do it yourself. Symfony is handy, but it's not magic... ;) https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security.html#securing-controllers-and-other-code